# How to put searchBar into appBar - Flutter?

Tags: flutter, appbar

I'm having trouble placing my search bar in the `AppBar`, 
right now my searchBar is below my `AppBar`, I tried use another `Container` into my `AppBar` but without success.

My code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
        child: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100),
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  print('klikniete');
                },
              ),
            ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Container(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: fetchOrders(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (_ordersForDisplay.length == null) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(child: Text("Ładowanie...")),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: _ordersForDisplay.length + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return index == 0 ? _searchBar() : _listItem(index - 1);
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ), 
      )
    );
  }

_searchBar() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Wyszukaj po mieście...'
        ),
        onChanged: (text) {
          text = text.toLowerCase();
          setState(() {
            _ordersForDisplay = _orders.where((note) {
              var noteTitle = note.city.toLowerCase();
              return noteTitle.contains(text);
            }).toList();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }



  _listItem(index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(item: _ordersForDisplay[index])),
      ),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 32.0, bottom: 32.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                _ordersForDisplay[index].firstName,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                _ordersForDisplay[index].lastName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade600
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i'm put searchBar into my appBar by use `title: _searchBar`, next I remove 
`return index == 0 ? _searchBar() : _listItem(index - 1);` and paste only `return _listItem(index, context)`, but right now i have error: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1`

Comment: use the AppBar's bottom property example: `AppBar(bottom:_searchBar,)`

Comment: @TinusJackson it throw me ```type 'Padding' is not a subtype of type 'PreferredSizeWidget'```

Comment: @TinusJackson  I use ```title: _searchBar()``` but i have another problem, could you look at the edited post ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting to this

[image]

OR this?

[image]

Code:

```
class CustomSearchBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomSearchBarDemoState createState() => _CustomSearchBarDemoState();
}

class _CustomSearchBarDemoState extends State<CustomSearchBarDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text("Search",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
        centerTitle: true,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
         child: Container(
          //  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),   
            color: Colors.grey[300],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.grey),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: ' Search by name or address',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.mic,color: Colors.grey,),
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ) ,
      ),

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

OR

```
class CustomSearchBarDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomSearchBarDemoState createState() => _CustomSearchBarDemoState();
}

class _CustomSearchBarDemoState extends State<CustomSearchBarDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: 
      PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
         child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),   
            color: Colors.grey[300],
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.grey),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintText: ' Search by name or address',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {

                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    child: Icon(Icons.mic,color: Colors.grey,),
                    onTap: () {

                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ) ,
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can basically add any widget in the title property of appbar.

```
AppBar(
          title: TextField(
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: " Search...",
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () { 
                      },)
   ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
                  ),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100),
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  print('klikniete');
                },
              ),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: thanks, I use ```title: _searchBar()``` but i have another problem, could you look at the edited post ?

Comment: What problem are you having now?

Comment: look at the main post, I wrote at the bottom

Comment: after using ```title``` it show me two appbar, on in appbar and another below appbar

Comment: @nowekonto Yea, your code shows two search bar. because you are rendering one at the app bar and another one from the first position of the listview. Remove the one from the title or one from the ListView, that will leave only 1 searchbar.

Comment: ```listItem(index+1,context)``` not help :(

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What error are you getting?

Comment: With this error, i my ```ListView.builder``` does not work, in mean that not show me my object on the scrren in my list

Comment: ```RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 4```

Comment: Have you planned to keep the searchbar in the title and remove the one from the listview, or vice-versa? If in case you need it in the list then ,You need _listItem(index - 1); Sorry not index+1